# Windows Azure notification hub registration ID and token location?

Tags: android, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am using Windows Azure notification hub to send notifications to the users in my Android application. I have some kind of a chat in my application, and I would like to send notifications only to specific users. I suppose that I have to specify their tags when sending notifications. Where are those tags stored? How am I sure that the user is properly registered?
I have this code for registering users:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void registerWithNotificationHubs() {
       new AsyncTask() {
          @Override
          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
             try {
                String regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                hub.register(regid, "tag");
             } catch (Exception e) {
                return e;
             }
             return null;
         }
       }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

When not using a tag, the notifications work and they are sent to all the devices. I'd like to add a tag and send the notification to specific tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We call it tags not tokens. You can specify one ore more tags for each device registration and then use those tags to rout messages to particular user or group. Documentation id [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx).

Comment: Yes thanks, I know it's tags, I edited the post. I am aware that you can target specific tags, but I want to know where can I see all these tags? The problem is that the tags I would like to assign to devices would be dinamic, and I wouldn't know them. They could be a string containing the email of the user. And then I would like to see them and send a notification to a user by specifying user's email

Comment: If I am user1 then I have some identifier in your system - email, DB Id or something like this. When user2 sends me a message he knows my identifier somehow. So if my registration has a tag which equals to my identifier, then message my be sent to that tag and I will receive one.

If it does not work for some reasons just let me know and I'll help to find the solution.

Comment: Yes, just as I thought it would work. But how am I sure that the tag I assigned is really assigned? I thought that there would be a table or something in the notifications hub where I could see all those tokens and registrations. But I guess the only way to check that is to test it.

Comment: Notification Hub allows to retrieve registration(s) by tag if you really need to do so. But what is happening in most cases - each time application is lunched on device, it gets registrationId from GCM and then creates/updates Notification Hub registration. So if user uses application, then his Id presents in the Notification Hub. Also think about what are you going to do if you find out that particular user is not registered in the Notification Hub? Are you going to create registration for him? In this case you must provide his GCM registrationId which may be obtained only from his device.

Comment: I am sorry for taking this long to answer, I was out of town. So I managed to use tags to target specific users of my app. It worked as you said, I registered them with sender_id and a tag, and then in node.js in my Windows Azure mobile service I send the notification only to those tags. Thank you!